# URL Percent Encoding only the query in PHP like in Swift

Tags: php, swift, wordpress, url, urlencode

I want to encode an URL in PHP in the same behaviour in Swift here is the Swift example:

```
let string = "http://site.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Hidløgsma.jpg"

let encodedString = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

result : `http://site.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Hidl%25F8gsma.jpg`

how to get the same result in PHP i.e. a function that encode only the query and returns the same result with the example string. Here is documentation about Swift function:

`func addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters allowedCharacters: CharacterSet) -> String?`

> Entire URL strings cannot be percent-encoded, because each URL
>   component specifies a different set of allowed characters. For
>   example, the query component of a URL allows the “@” character, but
>   that character must be percent-encoded in the password component.
>
> UTF-8 encoding is used to determine the correct percent-encoded
>   characters. Any characters in allowedCharacters outside of the 7-bit
>   ASCII range are ignored.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding

`urlQueryAllowed`

> The query component of a URL is the component immediately following a
>   question mark (?). For example, in the URL
>   http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1#jumpLink, the query
>   component is key1=value1.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1416698-urlqueryallowed

Comment: You need to parse the path after the domain, encode each component that is part of the query using `urlencode` and re-build the url.

Comment: Preferably you should really encode those components individually as you assemble the URL, not after the fact. What if instead of ø you have a / in your value? Then it's entirely ambiguous whether that should be encoded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky:

Firstly of all I suggest using the [PECL HTTP extension](http://php.net/manual/fa/book.http.php)

Assuming you don't have `/` that need to be encoded, then you can do the following.

```
<?php

$parsed = parse_url("http://site.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Hidløgsma.jpg"); //Get the URL bits
if (isset($parsed["path"])) {
    $parsed["path"] = implode("/", array_map('urlencode', explode("/",$parsed["path"]))); //Break the path according to slashes and encode each path bit
}
//If you need to do the query string then you can also do:
if (isset($parsed["query"])) {
    parse_str($parsed["query"],$result); //Parse and encode the string
    $parsed["query"] = http_build_query(
        array_combine(
            array_map('urlencode', array_keys($result)),
            array_map('urlencode', array_values($result))
        )
    );
}
//Maybe more parts need encoding?

//http_build_url needs the PECL HTTP extension
$rebuilt = http_build_url($parsed); //Probably better to use this instead of writing your own
```

However if you don't want to install an extension for this then the simple thing to do in order to replace `http_build_url` is:

```
$rebuilt = $parsed["scheme"]
    ."://"
    .(isset($parsed["user"])?$parsed["user"]:"")
    .(isset($parsed["pass"])?":".$parsed["pass"]:"")
    .$parsed["host"]
    .(isset($parsed["port"])?":".$parsed["port"]:"")
    .(isset($parsed["path"])?$parsed["path"]:"")
    .(isset($parsed["query"])?"?".$parsed["query"]:"")
    .(isset($parsed["fragment"])?"#".$parsed["fragment"]:"");

print_r($rebuilt);
```

Full demo at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65a3da9a92c6f55a45138c73beee7cba43bb09c3